# Hensel Lifting with a non-simple root

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I was doing a problem and it involves lifting a root x= 55, from mod $2^{10}$ to a solution mod $2^{19}$ but the root is non simple, i.e. $$f'(x)  \equiv 0  (mod 2)$$

Here, 
$f(x) = x^{3} - 9x + 8 \equiv 0 $  $(mod 2^{10})$

Where x = 55 is a solution of f(x).

I am wondering how I go about trying to lift to this power modulus.

Comment: Maybe substitute to find $(55+2^{10}x)^3-9(55+2^{10}x)+8\equiv0\pmod{2^{19}}$?

Comment: You could use the fact that $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x-8)$. You can do any kind of Hensel on the quadratic factor, and your desired number is the nonunit root. Alternatively, you can write $g(x)=f(x+1)=x(x^2 + 3x - 6)$ and work with the quadratic factor here. In addition, there are several ways of using Strong Hensel, which I guess you’re not aware of.

Comment: @awllower Thank you! I got there, I found that the lift was $x = 55+83 \cdot 2^{10}$ if you wanted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A general method is: If $x$ is a singular root $\mod p^j$, then either it lifts to p roots $\mod p^{j+1}$, or it lifts to no root, depending on if $f(x)$ is congruent to $0 \mod p^{j+1}$.

Comment: A remark. f(55) = 81*2^11, f'(55) = 4533*2^1. Since 11 >= 2*1 + 1, the solution 55 can be lifted to mod p^j with arbitrarily large j.